# Read from user input using array in Bash

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm struggling to create a logic to ask script user so many questions as I have in json array.

Let's say it looks like that (it is retrieved from a bigger json using `jq`):

```
[
  "key1",
  "key2",
  "key3",
  "key4",
  ...
]
```

I would like to ask script user questions like: what is the value for `key1`, what is the value for `key2` and so one. Every answer should be stored in some external file.
I'm using ZSH on Mac.

Comment: I would not recommend using a shell language for a program like this.

Comment: @chepner why not?

Comment: Because shells have horrible support for data structures.

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried so far, sample responses and the expected results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend iterating over the array of keys you want stored, then prompting the user and storing the variables dynamically in the loop. Here's a rough implementation of how I would do it:

```bash
json_array='[
  "key1",
  "key2",
  "key3",
  "key4"
]'

# `jq` idea + syntax borrowed from @Philippe
(jq -r '.[]' <<< "$json_array") | while read -r key; do
  echo -n "What is the value for $key? > "
  read -r value < /dev/tty

  # Now you have the input stored in $value, so you can do
  # whatever you want with it. If you want to store it in a
  # file, this is one simple example of to do it:
  echo "$key=$value"  >> userInput.txt
done
```

Comment: That looks nice, however I cannot just declare it as an array as I have json type of array

Comment: @Murakami my answer has been updated to meet your requirements :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
#!/usr/bin/ env bash

json_array='[
  "key1",
  "key2",
  "key3",
  "key4"
]'

while read -r key; do
  echo -n "What is the value for $key? > " > /dev/tty
  read -r value < /dev/tty
  echo "$key=$value"
done < <(jq -r '.[]' <<< "$json_array") > userInput.txt
```

Comment: The prompt is currently not displayed to the user, it is echoed into the `userInput.txt` file. Other than that, neat method!

Comment: @AaronMeese Indeed, updated.